# How to restrict the GPU memory size in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, out-of-memory

I'm implementing an algorithm out-of-core. The GPU memory size available to me is 4GB. However, to test and compare my algorithm with other versions on smaller datasets, I would like to restrict the memory size on GPU available to me. Is there any way to do this?

(I can always not use the large amount of memory present, however, I've to show that if the memory used by other versions exceed the available memory, then the other versions crash, whereas my algorithm continues to run out of core, and hence it would be great if there's a way to restrict the global memory size available on the GPU, programmatically or otherwise).

Comment: Can't you just *not use* a portion of available memory? Or `cudaMalloc` a dummy pointer with the size you would like to be taken away from available memory at the beginning of your program?

Comment: For comparison purposes, I can't just 'not use' the memory. However, the dummy pointer trick seems to be a good  option. Let me try it. Thanks.

Comment: @Farzad your dummy pointer suggestion seems reasonable.  If you post it as an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to `cudaMalloc` a dummy pointer with the size you would like to be taken away from available memory at the beginning of your program.